# Coordinate Vector Fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the following [notes](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/courses/m225/handouts/divgradcurl3.pdf) about coordinate systems in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and it lists four properties that coordinate vector fields should have. For the $(x,y)$ system and the coordinate vectors $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j}$, they are:

1. They are orthogonal.
2. They are unit vectors.
3. $\mathbf{i}$ points in the direction in which $x$ increases and $y$ is constant, and $\mathbf{j}$ points in the direction in which $y$ increases and $x$ is constant.
4. $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ represent differentiation of a function by $x$ and $y$. What this means is that if $f$ is a differentiable function, then
   $$
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = D_{\mathbf{i}} f \text{ and } \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = D_{\mathbf{j}} f
   $$

In the first paragraph on the second page, it's written

> Unfortunately, for an arbitrary
> coordinate system it is *impossible* to satisfy all four of the properties above. (It is a fairly
> deep theorem in differential geometry that the only coordinate systems with coordinate vector fields that satisfy all four properties are Euclidean coordinates.)

My question is, which theorem is referenced here?

Is it related to the necessity of having a vanishing Lie bracket, i.e two linearly independent vector fields $X$ and $Y$ must satisfy $[X, Y] = 0$ in order to find coordinates with $X = x_u$ and $Y = x_v$ ? So is it related to symmetry of higher-order derivatives?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen this way of thinking about it.  This is very interesting and I'd like to see the answer.  Seems hard to believe to me.

Comment: I think this is the first Theorem proved by Riemann that the existence is equivalent to vanishing of the curvatures.

Comment: See Theorem 6.2 [here](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~wendl/pub/connections_chapter6.pdf)

Comment: You can alternately say it has more to do with the othonormality. Any set of local coordinates $x^i$ induce coordinate vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, which always commute, but they are not in general orthonormal. The "deep theorem" is that _only_ euclidean coorinates induce orthonormal vector fields.